# OLS biasedness in AR(1) model

Tags: least-squares, autoregressive, unbiased-estimator

I am trying to show why the OLS estimator in time series models is not conditionally unbiased when using a zero-mean strong AR(1) model. From what I've read so far, this can be done through a Monte Carlo simulation as in [here](https://absalon.instructure.com/files/2223238/download?wrap=1),[here](https://absalon.ku.dk/files/1902650/download?download_frd=1), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269314/how-to-show-the-inconsistency-of-the-ols-estimator-for-unit-root-ar1-processes). Is this the only way we can prove it?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240383/why-is-ols-estimator-of-ar1-coefficient-biased/241063#241063

Comment: Not unrelated https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313119

Comment: @RichardHardy, yes, thank you for your suggestion!